# how to show different status when shell idle in tmux

Tags: tmux

I'm running multiple screen by tmux.
I wish tmux could show 'red' color status if one window stop send out any text for some seconds.  Is there that function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is this function, you can use

```
set-window-option monitor-silence [seconds]
set-window-option window-status-activity-fg red
```

Answer (score 0):

I *usually* want to see activity, but I want to see silence often enough that I've made a toggle for it in my .tmux.conf:

```
# Toggle silence checking or activity checking in window
bind * setw monitor-silence 0\; setw monitor-activity on\; display "Monitoring for window activity"
bind '#' setw monitor-silence 30\; setw monitor-activity off\; display "Monitoring for window silence"
```